# How to use lodash once in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I have an input like below.

```
          <input
            type="text"
            maxlength="50"
            v-on:input="query = $event.target.value"
            v-on:keyup.enter="once(search)"
          />
```

And there is a method called search and once of lodash.

```
import _ from 'lodash'

methods:{
    once(func){
        return _.once(func)
    },
    async search(){
         // An api call is in it
    }
}
```

But in this case, it says "search is undefined".
How can I make this case well?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with lodash or lodash once. The error "search is undefined" is not specific to lodash or lodash once, but a general javascript error. You could have copy pasted the error you are facing on google ("javascript error: x is not defined") but instead you pasted it on stackoverflow. This shows lack of research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is given while your trying to pass a method to your function while it expects a data element.

Instead of using once of lodash, you better could use the eventhandler of vue itself once https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers.

Use:

```
v-on:keyup.enter.once
```

Comment: It works well. But The thing is I want to run a function again after getting 'return result'. That is my goal is I want to wait the result although entering many times before getting result.

Comment: Lodash is doing the same as vue stop;) But if i understand it correct, you only want to prevent that the calls runs simultaneous at the same time? but not one after each other?